# Why cant null be returned to a $.getJSON() function?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Given the following controller method

```
public ActionResult TestJsonResult()
{
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // return null;
}
```

and client side script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("TestJsonResult", "Test")';
$.getJSON(url, function (result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log('returned a result');
    } else {
        console.log('returned null'); // this is never hit
    }
}).fail(function (result) {
    console.log('failed'); // this is hit for return Json(null); and return null;
    // result is status 200 OK
});
```

then the outputs for the 3 return value options are

```
return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // outputs "returned a result"
return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // outputs "failed"
return null; // outputs "failed"
```

Acording to the [specification](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc7159.txt.pdf)

> 3. Values
>
>    A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names:
>      false **null** true

If a JSON value can be `null`, why does the `else` block never get hit when the return value is `null` and is this a failing of the [Json()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/dd504936(v=vs.118).asp) method or is it that a `null` value cannot be properly represented as JSON when returned to the `getJSON()` method?

Note, using `$.ajax()` without specifying `dataType:` will hit the `else` block when the controller method is `return null;` (I assume because the return value is interpreted as something other than json).

Note: using MVC-4 and jquery-1.9.1

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your browser's dev tools console show as the response for the AJAX call in the cases that fail?

Comment: It gives a 200 OK response - so it returning fine, which make me think that it could also be related to the `getJSON()` function because it must be failing on the client side

Comment: 200 OK is just the status code, there should be an actual body for the response that contains the JSON string. Whatever that is, it's likely something that isn't actually valid JSON.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Thats part of what I don't understand - there is nothing indicated. The Network Response tab just says _This request has no response data avaliable_

Comment: Not sure why but It never fails at my end, I did exactly what you did here.

Comment: @Manoz, Which version of jquery? (just found something suggesting there was a change made in 1.9 which may explain it - although it was related to an empty string not `null` - I'll need to explore it a bit more)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, this cdn build- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: @Manoz, That's the version I'm using. If your claiming its working (hits the `else` block using `return Json(null..);`) then maybe there's something else my end. I'll create a fresh project in the morning and test it again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes I am very much sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` will return empty string. And empty string is not a valid json string. So `$.getJSON` would be failed. You can use javascript try `JSON.parse("")` it will throw a error.

Comment: I don't think that's correct because `return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` returns a `JsonResult` and its `Data` property is `null` (not an empty string)

Comment: I have also tested `return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and surprising that actually hits the `else` block (no error is thrown), so I guess `$.getJSON()` does not use `JSON.parse()` internally (I'll need to explore that in some more detail to try and understand whats happening)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right, `return Json(null)`  not return empty string. And i use fiddler check it, i found it content-length is 0 and response body has no data

Comment: After a bit of testing with various versions of jquery, I found that its only 1.9+ where this occurs (1.7 for example does hit the `else` block) so there has been some change which does not appear to be documented.

Comment: I have also used fiddler checked `return Json(string.Empty)`, and it response content-length is 2 and response body is empty string. So i think you can see the jquery getJson source code to find more detail.